# VBA Code to insert new rows with merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

All,

I am in need of some serious assistance.  I did not create the excel spreadsheet but I am trying to correct it for a friend.

Here is the problem, this spreadsheet is used by numerous people in the company and it does not always contain the same number of rows.

I used the following VBA code to insert a new row that copies the cells above and pastes to a new row.  The problem is that it is not merging the cells and is not carrying the formula down to the next row in AM Column.

How can I modify the existing VBA code to merge the cells and keep the formatting from the above row and to modify the formula for the next row

I cannot find where to attach a copy of the database I am using so that you can see the database.  Please help on this

Below is the code that I am currently using: (BTW)---I am VBA Stupid so please try to keep it simple.  The code below was borrowed from someone else to fit my needs.

Here is the formula in Column AM that needs to be copied and modified for the next row:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!A2:D5,MATCH($AK$13,(Sheet3!A1:D1),0),MATCH($AL$13,(Sheet3!E2:E5),0)),0)

Here is what the next formula should read:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!A2:D5,MATCH($AK$14,(Sheet3!A1:D1),0),MATCH($AL$14,(Sheet3!E2:E5),0)),0)

```
Sub InsertRowFormulas()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range
Selection.EntireRow.Insert
For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow)
If cell.HasFormula Then
cell.Copy cell.Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells only merged across? I'm asking because your question is written like you only need to copy one row at a time.

Comment: Yes, I am only doing on row at a time.  This will allow personnel to only add as many rows as they require.

Comment: I meant to ask whether there are any cells merged vertically. It sounds like you only have horizontally merged cells.

Comment: the Cells that need to be merged and centered are B-H, I-S, T-X, Y-AI

Comment: Only horizontal merging for the specific cells across the row

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues you need to address.

First, you need to set up your formula to have the [correct reference locking](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010081865.aspx#BMusing_references_in_formulas), so that when you autofill the formula in new rows the references are updated correctly. If you want a row or column reference to not be adjusted when the formula is copied, you prefix it with a $.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$2:$D$5,
               MATCH($AK13,Sheet3!$A$1:$D$1,0),
               MATCH($AL13,Sheet3!$E$2:$E$5,0)),0)
```

With the correct locking, you can just copy the entire row to retain the merged cells. I'm not really sure if a macro is required for this - it would probably be easier to train the users of the spreadsheet how to copy rows, which is a pretty simple operation in Excel.

```
Dim dest As Range

Selection.EntireRow.Insert
Set dest = Selection.Worksheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 1)
dest.Offset(1).Resize(, dest.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy dest
```

Comment: I tried to use the above formula for but it was not referencing the correct cells, so I corrected it to reference the cells, but the problem is that when the next row is generated, the formula is not adding a value to reference the next row number.  Such as the following:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$2:$D$5,MATCH($AK$52,Sheet3!$A$1:$D$1,0),MATCH($AL$52,Sheet3!$E$2:$E$5,0)),0)                                                 Then the next row down should read:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$2:$D$5,MATCH($AK$53,Sheet3!$A$1:$D$1,0),MATCH($AL$53,Sheet3!$E$2:$E$5,0)),0)

Comment: Remove the $ from before the rows or columns that you want to change when the formula is copied.